# When input has text, bootstrap change its color

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form input like this (label text is black):

[image]

When I type something in it (and after leave the field), it stays like this (label text is gray):

[image]

How can I keep the label black?

This is my input code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label class="label-black">@Html.LabelFor(g => g.Street)</label>
            <input asp-for="Street" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will probably need to see a full example of this to see what is going on. Add a stack snippet or jsfiddle with a verifiable example of the problem if you can.

Comment: Did you intend to nest labels? `Html.LabelFor()` will create a `<label>` element. You can remove the outer `<label>` and reduce that to `@Html.LabelFor(g => g.Street, new { @class="label-black" })`

Comment: @Jasen I didn't know that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize that style as being from [twitter-bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/), but if it is then the following CSS rule should override it:

```
label.label-black {
    color: #000;
}
```

If this is not sufficient to override the current style you may need to further specify the selector:

```
form .form-group label.label-black {
    color: #000;
}
```

Note: *That rule must be applied after any other CSS declarations in order to override them.*

And finally if doesn't work, then there may be some JavaScript involved, in which case no amount of CSS over specification will help, since the JS style will be applied later.

Comment: I think may be some javascript then, because it do not worked.